# Angularfire get unique id after $push

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I need to get the unique ID after a $push

```
fb.$push({
  fieldOne: 'monkey moo',
  fieldTwo: 'show',
  insertTime: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
});
then(get -K3Vevty-NtQ30wdJAUw)
```

What I need is the id unique like "-K3Vevty-NtQ30wdJAUw"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `.$push()` but there is a `.$save()` that returns a promise with the new record added.

```
var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
list.$add({ foo: "bar" }).then(function(ref) {
  var id = ref.key();
  console.log("added record with id " + id);
  list.$indexFor(id); // returns location in the array
});
```

[Read the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-addnewdata) for more info.

Comment: Hi, I have been using $push successfully to add new records, but I take your point regarding the docs, I will read them now and respond back:)

Comment: What version of AngularFire are you using?

Comment: <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.1/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>

Comment: I realise my problem, not reading the official docs and not using the up to date version.

Comment: Yes, you should upgrade to AF 1.1.3. 0.8 is no longer supported and is obsolete.